# How to toggle axis for local selection in edit mode

Tags: user-interface, 3d, blender

I have a typical Blender problem: I accidently have toggled these axis that appear on every selection in edit mode. How to toggle them back?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Origin to 3D Cursor (Object » Set Origin » [option]) to reset the origin to wherever the 3D Cursor is located in the Scene;

Geometry to Origin: reposition mesh relative to Origin.
Origin to Geometry: repositions Origin relative to mesh.
Origin to 3D Cursor: repositions Origin at 3D Cursors location.
Origin to Center of Mass (Surface): resets Origin based on total surface area.
Origin to Center of Mass (Volume): resets Origin based on bounding box volume.